Modify data with dplyr
I have a dataset that looks like this:
    ID  Main Size Distance
    1    1    2     0
    1    0    3     1
    1    0    4     2
    2    1    5     0
    2    0    6     2
    2    0    7     3

For each ID, and only for those IDs where Main is 0, I want to multiply size by distance, then sum up these results and store them in a new database that also includes ID. The result should be something like this:
    ID  Result
    1    11
    2    33

How can I do this? I tried different ways but I end up with NAs and NaNs. Thanks!

What did you try?

Would you want to keep IDs where there is no 0 value on Main?

You could try
df %>%
    summarise(Result = sum(Size * Distance * !Main), .by = ID)

which gives
  ID Result
1  1     11
2  2     33


This suggestion was the most helpful, although I adapted it to my data and merged it a bit with @Edward ´s solution. Thanks!

filter(df, Main==0) |>
  summarise(Result=sum(Size * Distance), .by=ID)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
     ID Result
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     11
2     2     33


df |>
  filter(Main == 0L) |>
  summarise(Result = Size %*% Distance, .by = ID)

#   ID Result
# 1  1     11
# 2  2     33

Where
df <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:2, each = 3L),
  Main = rep(c(1L, 0L, 0L), 2),
  Size = 2:7,
  Distance = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L)
)


Compute the Size * Distance vector and subset it with your condition before summing:
library(dplyr)

df |>
  summarize(Result = sum((Size * Distance)[Main == 0L]), .by = ID)
#   ID Result
# 1  1     11
# 2  2     33

